# Centering divs and giving them top/bottom positioning?

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div, but at the same time be able to use something like `top: 100px;` in my code. Is this possible? I notice that if I say `position: fixed;` then the top/bottom styles will work, but `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` are disabled. How can I get both features at once? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/nb6zY/

Comment: @Arunes: the OP is looking for a way to center an element using position, not Margins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you're using this for, the easiest way might be to use two elements: an "invisible" one with fixed position and an inner element which is centered. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CCqUn/

```
<div>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

```
div {
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    width:100%;
    height:0; /* In case of z-index issues; this element should be "hidden" */
}
div p {
    width:200px;   
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/nb6zY/2/

Setting the margins of a fixed element will work, just not with 'auto'.  I use the following technique often when creating modals:

```
div {
  width:100px;
  position:fixed; 
  top:100px;
  left:50%; 
  margin-left:-50px;
}
```

This only works if you know the width of the div you want to center.  The trick is setting margin-left to a negative 'half' of the div width.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use a containing element (99% of the time a `div`), together with margins / padding, rather than top coordinates (which tend to be more for exact positioning relative to other elements whose position and size are known). Check out the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Some content in here..!
    </div>
</div>
```

...then the CSS:

```
.container
{
    width: 100%;
}

.content
{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: ORANGE;

    /* set it to the center of the container, plus move it down */
    /* using 100px for the top margin */
    margin: 100px auto 0px;
}
```

This would set the left and right margins to `auto`, leave the bottom margin `0px`, and make the top margin `100px`.

Obviously, for center-positioning of elements, the `0px auto` margin setting would be the best, but if you know the exact coordinates at which you'd like the element to be positioned, *relative to the container*, you can try the following too (CSS):

```
.container
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.content
{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: ORANGE;

    /* exact coordinates, relative to the container (parent) */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Hope this helps!